# Load Multiple Javascript files in serial

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using **$.Deferred** to load mulitiple files:

```
$.when(
        $.getScript("/assets/libs/swal/sweet-alert.min.js"), 
        $.getScript("/assets/js/jquery.form.js"), 
        $.getScript("/assets/js/jquery.preloader.js"), 
        $.getScript("/assets/js/item_inventory.js"), 
        $.Deferred( function(defer) {
            $(defer.resolve);
        }).promise()
    ).done(function() {

    });
```

But when i see in the console, files are not loaded in serial way like

1. sweet-alert.min.js
2. jquery.form.js
3. jquery.preloader.js
4. item_inventory.js

Then problem is the last `item_inventory.js` has some dependency related to `jquery.preloader.js` so its generate error sometimes, is there any way i can load then in serial without any third-party library?

Comment: may be this link help you  . http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/  . use callback function ( success ) after each file load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another suggestion is to use `jQuery.Deferred()` this way:

```
var d1 = new $.Deferred();
var d2 = new $.Deferred();
var d3 = new $.Deferred();
var d4 = new $.Deferred();

$.when( d1, d2, d3, d4 ).done(function () {
    console.log('Loaded in order.');
});

d1.resolve($.getScript("/assets/libs/swal/sweet-alert.min.js"));
d2.resolve($.getScript("/assets/js/jquery.form.js"));
d3.resolve($.getScript("/assets/js/jquery.preloader.js"));
d4.resolve($.getScript("/assets/js/item_inventory.js"));
```

Comment: so if i have 10 files then i have to define `$.Deferred()` 10 times?

Comment: @jogesh_pi it is just another approach suggested. yet there are other ways too.

Comment: This is what i want in serial with `$.Deferred`, and also `$.getScript()` chaining also work.  Thank you

Comment: How does this method ensure they are loaded in order?

Answer (score 2):

`$.getScript` return `Deferred` object which you can use to build serial chain. Something like this:

```
$.getScript("/assets/libs/swal/sweet-alert.min.js").done(function () {
    $.getScript("/assets/js/jquery.form.js").done(function () {
        $.getScript("/assets/js/jquery.preloader.js").done(function () {
            $.getScript("/assets/js/item_inventory.js");
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the callback function of `$.getScript()` to achieve this.

```
$.getScript( "/assets/js/jquery.preloader.js", function() {
  $.getScript("/assets/js/item_inventory.js")
});
```

This way, `item_inventory.js` will be loaded only after `jquery.preloader.js` is loaded.

---

Source: [jQuery.getScript() Documentation by jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jQuery .then()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) to load the script like so:

```
$.when(
    $.getScript("/assets/libs/swal/sweet-alert.min.js"), 
    $.getScript("/assets/js/jquery.form.js"), 
    $.getScript("/assets/js/jquery.preloader.js")
).then(function() {
    return $.getScript("/assets/js/item_inventory.js")
}).done(function() {
    console.log("done")
});
```

Note that because `$.then()` returns it's own promise, it's chainable, and you can nest as many dependencies as you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is the exact opposite of a serial flow. You are invoking all of your `$.getScript` calls together, and passing their `Deferred` objects to `$.when`. This means all four are running in the background concurrently, independently of each other.

If you want to synchronize their loading using `$.when`'s promise-like API, you should probably do something like:

```
$.when(
    $.getScript("/assets/libs/swal/sweet-alert.min.js"), 
    $.getScript("/assets/js/jquery.form.js"), 
    $.getScript("/assets/js/jquery.preloader.js")
).done(function() {
    $.getScript("/assets/js/item_inventory.js"), 
}).done(function() {
    // do whatever
});
```

This code loads `sweet-alert.min.js`, `jquery.form.js`, and `jquery.preloader.js` *concurrently*, waits until *all* finished loading, and *only then* loads `item_inventory.js`